# R: flexdashboard shrinks content, any way to prevent this?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I ran R markdown with 8 stocks and with 12 stocks.  As you can see the stock charts get increasingly smaller.  Is there any way to force flexdashboard to keep a larger width? I don't mind vertically scrolling when there are 12 or more stocks on a screen.

```
rmarkdown::render('foo.Rmd')
# creates foo.html
```

[image]

**foo.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Semiconductor: 5 years"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(quantmod)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
getSymbols(c("APH","IBM","CCL","TSS","HSY","COH","QRVO","CMA","RJF","ABBV","SCHW","RTN"), src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01")
```

Row
-------------------------------------
### APH
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(APH, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### IBM
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(IBM, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### CCL
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(CCL, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### TSS
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(TSS, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```



Row
-------------------------------------
### HSY
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(HSY, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### COH
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(COH, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### QRVO
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(QRVO, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### CMA
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(CMA, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```



Row
-------------------------------------
### RJF
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(RJF, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### ABBV
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(ABBV, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### SCHW
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(SCHW, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### RTN
```{r, fig.height=5}
chartSeries(RTN, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```
````

**foo.Rmd (with vertical scroll)**

````
---
title: "Semiconductor: 5 years"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(quantmod)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
getSymbols(c("MTB","IVZ","UAL","MOS","MCK","ADSK","LEG","STT","RMD","EBAY","RF","FIS"), src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01")
```

Row
-------------------------------------
### MTB
```{r}
chartSeries(MTB, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### IVZ
```{r}
chartSeries(IVZ, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### UAL
```{r}
chartSeries(UAL, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### MOS
```{r}
chartSeries(MOS, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```



Row
-------------------------------------
### MCK
```{r}
chartSeries(MCK, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### ADSK
```{r}
chartSeries(ADSK, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### LEG
```{r}
chartSeries(LEG, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### STT
```{r}
chartSeries(STT, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```



Row
-------------------------------------
### RMD
```{r}
chartSeries(RMD, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### EBAY
```{r}
chartSeries(EBAY, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### RF
```{r}
chartSeries(RF, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### FIS
```{r}
chartSeries(FIS, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```
````

Comment: Flex is designed to work hard to fit your content, perhaps you need to reconsider your layout to have fewer plots per row.

Comment: Alernatively, add `vertical_layout: scroll` to your YAML as described [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html).

Answer (score 3):

A combination of **Row {data-height=200)** and  **{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}** and **vertical_layout: scroll** has solved the issue for me.

**semi.Rmd** ...    `R -e "rmarkdown::render('semi.Rmd')"`

````
---
title: "Semiconductor: 5 years"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(quantmod)
# 4 stocks
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
getSymbols(c("INTC","TXN", "QCOM","NVDA","AVGO","STM","AMD","CY","TSM","ADI"), src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01")
```

Row {data-height=200}
-------------------------------------
### Intel
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(INTC, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### Qualcomm
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(QCOM, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### Texas Instruments
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(TXN, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### Broadcom
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(AVGO, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

Row {data-height=200}
-------------------------------------
### ST Microelectronics
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(STM, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### AMD
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(AMD, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### Cypress
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(CY, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### NVDA
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(NVDA, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

Row {data-height=200}
-------------------------------------
### TSMC
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(TSM, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### Analog Devices
```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=5}
chartSeries(ADI, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```
````

Comment: Your answer is specific to your content and not able to be generalised as a solution for others with a similar question to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical_layout: scroll` to your YAML

```
---
title: "Semiconductor: 5 years"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---
```

Getting the plot to fill each box in a way to meet your tastes using this method requires experimentation, according to the package [site](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html).

> We’ve specified an explicit `fig.height` and `fig.width` for each chart so that their rendered size fits their flex container as closely as possible. Note that the ideal values for these dimensions typically need to be determined by experimentation.

To improve the viewing of the plots, you may prefer to switch to tabs

````
---
title: "Semiconductor: 5 years"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(quantmod)
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
getSymbols(c("APH","IBM","CCL","TSS","HSY","COH","QRVO","CMA","RJF","ABBV","SCHW","RTN"), src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01")
```

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
### APH
```{r}
chartSeries(APH, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### IBM
```{r}
chartSeries(IBM, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```

### CCL
```{r}
chartSeries(CCL, type="line", subset="last 5 years", TA=NULL)
```
````

Comment: There is too much whitespace around the rows now, that space needs to be minimized.

Comment: @AG1, then remove the `fig.height` you've set on every chunk

Comment: Thanks for the hints, note that I do not want to use tabs.  I want to be able to scroll.  I added another variant of foo.Rmd to the initial question and there is still too much whitespace.

Comment: The use of {.tabset} avoids solving the issue.